# What is the maximum number of Thread count that we can give on the JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, mqtt, performance-testing, load-testing

I am using one AWS m5.2xlarge instance for doing the load test. This comes with the below specs.

1. CPU Size - 2500MHz
2. Memory Size - 32GiB

I am trying the MQTT Routing test and need to certify it for 200k concurrent threads. With my above specs of the server, I am getting below error after 12000 threads are created.

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/ezetap/hs_err_pid3645.log
```

I have increased the Java Heap size to the below-mentioned one.

```
"${HEAP:="-Xms8g -Xmx18g -Xss256k -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m"}"
```

I do not want to do the distributed tests as clubbing the reports to certify this is a tedious task. Can we increase the instance capacity to a higher combination of CPU, RAM, and networking capacity or is there any wiser way to achieve this?

Comment: How much memory a thread alone takes depends on your os and architecture and can range from 32K to 1024K. Assuming linux x64 it will use (approx.) 256K. 256K * 200000 = 512GB. So just to create the threads (and do nothing) you will already need 512G of memory, factor in JMeter and result parsing and yuo might even double that. Not to mention that 200000 is above the max number of ports (65k) you can assign. So no you cannot create 200000 threads with your current setup or with another setup.

Comment: What should be the approach next? Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Use distributed testing. You cannot do this with one machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many `2Lakh` is, but if it's higher than your:

1. [`kernel.pid_max`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-increase-pid-limits.html)
2. [`kernel.threads-max`](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/max-threads-per-process)
3. Maximum number of [processes](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)
4. Maximum [Number of ports](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793) in your system (which is 65535)

You will **have** to go for [distributed testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: Is there any way where we can get the results clubbed from each machine if we go for the distributed testing?

Comment: JMeter does it automatically, master machine collects results from slaves and puts them into single results file

Comment: Why is my Instance not loading the threads more than 12000? Is that the capacity of the same? Is there any property in the JMeter where I can increase the Max Available Threads? If we are able to go beyond 12k threads in one instance, at least up to 30k threads, we can reduce the number of slave machines for doing the distributed test. How to go beyond 12k users? Where is it getting restrained?